# Compile and run libgdx particle editor from source

Tags: java, compilation, libgdx

I'm trying to run the libgdx particle editor from source, but after I compile the gdx-tools.jar from ant, it does not have a main manifest and I cannot launch the .jar. How am I supposed to compile and use the particle editor?

Answer (score 0):

The particle editor isn't an Android App so there does not need to be any manifest data. To use the particle editor you can simply use the online start version. [Link](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDwQFjAB&url=http://libgdx.googlecode.com/svn/jws/particle-editor.jnlp&ei=gkN6UZ6fBIfYtQat_YHgBQ&usg=AFQjCNEslTHMExLFjRO7s4cpIFJylPnAsQ&sig2=Wl6lXZjF3xTn1dVRdoFdJg&bvm=bv.45645796,d.Yms&cad=rja)
You always have the current version if you use this startup. 
Else it should be possible to compile it to a Java Application and also be possible to use it as every other Java Application.

Here is the tutorial how to start the particle Editor out of the code:
[how to get the source](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SourceRunningDemos) 
[how to build libgdx](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SourceBuilding)

Comment: I was referring to a Main class indicated in the jar manifest, not AndroidManifest.xml, sorry.

Comment: Also, there was talk about deprecating the web launcher a long time ago.